# How to launch a JAVA GUI App inside a Linux Container from a Windows Host without 3rd party X Server

Tags: docker, xserver, x11-forwarding

I have a Linux container with a JAVA GUI Application that I'm trying to run from a Windows Host. Based on my research you can run a GUI app on a Windows host by installing 3rd party software like *VcXsrv Windows X Server*. Sadly, I'm don't have admin privileges so I can't install software freely also this process requires to disable Windows Access Control.

Is there a way that you can run a GUI app inside a Linux container from a Windows host without using 3rd party software?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the original goals of Java was to be runnable anywhere you can install a JVM.  Can you just run the `.jar` file using a native Windows JVM, rather than using Docker?  (Docker is not a good fit in general for interactive desktop GUI applications.)

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for your reply. Sadly, no. Running the application natively in Windows is not an option.